# Regex separanda por tipo de ocorrências, como fazer e a forma simples de alcançar?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-replace

Olá, estou trabalhando com user-agent e gostaria de uma ajuda.

Quero separar um valor de uma string que tem esse padrão:

```
Mozilla/<version> (<system-information>) <platform> (<platform-details>) <extensions>
```

**Exemplos existentes, entre milhares:**

> tipo 1:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36
```

> tipo 2

```
5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; MotoE2(4G-LTE) Build/LXI22.50-53.8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.76 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

> tipo 3

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
```

> **Forma da separação:**
>
> Dividir os valores a todo fechamento de parentasses externos,
>   independente de quantos tem de acordo com o padrão do user-agente
>   postado acima;
>
> **ou**
>
> Em outras palavras, sempre que haver uma sequencia de texto seguido com a abertura, textos dentro e fechamento do parentasse, deverá ser dividido do texto até o fechamento do parentasse de primeira ocorrência e assim por diante;
>
> **Regra a ser aplicada:** Caso tenha um parentasse dentro de algum que ocorreu primeiro, ele não deve ser dividido como o seu pai!

**Exemplos dos resultados esperados com os valores postados acima:**

tipo 1:

```
array (
0 => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) ',
1 => 'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ',
2 => 'Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'
);
```

tipo 2:

```
array (
0 => '5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; MotoE2(4G-LTE) Build/LXI22.50-53.8) ',
1 => 'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ',
2 => 'Chrome/47.0.2526.76 Mobile Safari/537.36'
);
```

tipo 3:

```
array (
0 => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0) ',
1 => 'Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0'
);
```

Acredito ter tentado explicar muito anteriormente, por isso fiz essa mega edição, tentando deixar as coisas mais claras, por favor se não fui, fique a vontade para perguntar...

Comment: Talvez não seja tão simples pq o formato varia muito, e particularmente um parênteses dentro de outro é complicado (embora não seja impossível). Mas não entendi, vc quer validar se a string está no formato certo ou extrair dados específicos dela? De qq forma, vc tentou com a função get_browser? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: @hkotsubo apenas separar os valores que postei como exemplos de acordo com todo fechamento do primeiro parentase. Não conhecia a função get_browser, estou dando uma olhada, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criar uma regex que interprete todos (ou vários) user agents é uma tarefa bem difícil, já que o [formato é muito aberto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2601492) e cobrir todos os casos me parece inviável.

Uma alternativa é usar a função [`get_browser`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php). Para usá-la, você deve habilitar a diretiva `browscap` no seu arquivo `php.ini`:

```
browscap = /caminho/do/arquivo/browscap.ini
```

Sendo que o arquivo `browscap.ini` deve estar na máquina também. [Neste link](http://browscap.org/stream?q=PHP_BrowsCapINI) tem um exemplo que pode ser baixado.

Uma vez configurado, basta passar a string:

```
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36';
$result = get_browser($user_agent, true);
```

O segundo parâmetro indica se será retornado um array (caso seja passado `true`), ou um objeto (caso seja passado `false`, que também é o valor *default* se este não for passado).

Os dados retornados são variados e cabe a você avaliar os respectivos valores e ver se é o que você precisa.

---

#### Regex

Como já dito, uma regex para interpretar toda a string do *user agent* é bem complicada. O mais difícil é verificar parênteses dentro de outros parênteses. **Analisar a string com um *loop* [seria bem mais fácil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524624) do que usar regex**, mas de qualquer forma fica o registro abaixo.

A solução abaixo não verifica toda a string, **e sim somente até o primeiro par de parênteses, que é o que foi pedido na pergunta**. Além disso, assume-se que a string possui o formato "nome/versão (texto)":

```
function parseUserAgent($user_agent) {
    if (preg_match('{^([^/]*)/?(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\(([^)(]+|(?3))*+\))}', $user_agent, $matches)) {
        echo($matches[1]).PHP_EOL; // Mozilla, em branco
        echo($matches[2]).PHP_EOL; // versão
        $p = preg_replace('/^\((.*)\)$/', '$1', $matches[3]);
        echo($p).PHP_EOL; // conteúdo dentro do primeiro par de parênteses
    }
}

parseUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36');
parseUserAgent('5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; MotoE2(4G-LTE) Build/LXI22.50-53.8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.76 Mobile Safari/537.36');
```

Detalhe que usei `{` e `}` para delimitar a regex (em vez de usar as barras -> `/...regex.../`). Isso permite que eu use as barras dentro da regex sem precisar escapar com `\`. Eu escolhi `{` e `}` porque eles não são usados na regex, assim eu economizo algumas teclas e deixo a regex um pouco menos difícil de ler.

A primeira parte é simples:

- `^` é o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) para "início da string", assim eu garanto que a regex não vai pegar algo no meio da string por acidente.
- `([^/]*)/?`: zero ou mais caracteres que não são `/`, para pegar todo o texto antes da primeira barra. Em seguida tem uma barra opcional. Isso pega o trecho "Mozilla/", por exemplo, mas também pode pegar a string vazia. Eu poderia usar `[a-zA-Z]*` também, pois aí limitaria este trecho para somente letras, mas estou sendo bem simplista aqui (se você sabe que as strings sempre serão *user agents*, por exemplo, pode se dar ao luxo de simplificar a regex sabendo que não há tanto risco de falsos positivos).
- `(\d+\.\d+)`: o número da versão, definido como "vários dígitos, seguido de ponto, seguido de vários dígitos"

Repare que tanto o trecho antes da barra quanto a versão estão entre parênteses. Isso forma [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), o que permite que eu recupere estes trechos posteriormente, como foi feito no código acima (`$matches[1]` pega o trecho que foi capturado no primeiro grupo, `$matches[2]` no segundo do grupo, etc).

Depois temos um ou mais espaços (`\s+`), e aí chegamos na parte complicada.

---

Para conseguir verificar pares de parênteses aninhados, o jeito foi apelar para [regex recursiva](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php). Explicando por partes:

- `\(` e `\)`: são os próprios parênteses (abertura e fechamento)
- `[^)(]+`: um ou mais caracteres que não seja `)` nem `(`
- `|`: significa "ou"

Todo este trecho está envolto em um par de parênteses: `(\(([^)(]+|(?3))*+\))`. Como é o terceiro par de parênteses, eu posso referenciá-lo de forma recursiva usando `(?3)`. Isso quer dizer que `(?3)` é recursivamente substituído por toda a sub-expressão dentro desses parênteses.

Ou seja, eu posso ter:

- uma abertura de parênteses, seguido de:

  - um ou mais caracteres que não são parênteses, **ou**
  - uma abertura de parênteses, seguido de:

    - um ou mais caracteres que não são parênteses, **ou**
    - uma abertura de parênteses, seguido de:

      - um ou mais caracteres que não são parênteses, **ou**
      - uma abertura de parênteses, seguido de:

        - e assim por diante...
      - seguido por um fechamento de parênteses
    - seguido por um fechamento de parênteses
  - seguido por um fechamento de parênteses
- seguido por um fechamento de parênteses

Isso garante que teremos sequências de parênteses bem formados.

Em seguida eu obtenho os *matches*. Para o terceiro *match*, os parênteses também fazem parte do que foi capturado, então eu apenas removo-os usando [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), mas fica a seu critério remover ou não.

A saída é:

> Mozilla
>   5.0
>   X11; Linux x86_64
>   
>   5.0
>   Linux; Android 5.0.2; MotoE2(4G-LTE) Build/LXI22.50-53.8

Comment: ficou ótimo porém não funcionou da forma que esperava e marquei como resposta certa, mas podemos corrigir... utilizando apenas preg_match('{^([^/]*)/?(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\(([^)(]+|(?3))*+\))}', $user_agent, $matches) ele me retorna a array com os valores separados quase certo, no caso que citei agora apenas com preg_match ele retorna com 5 valores na array, de 0 a 4, teria como retornar com toda a string separada? como nos exemplos da pergunta, vou editar o ultimo para parecer mais claro!

Comment: @RobertCezar Daria pra fazer `preg_match('{^([^/]*)/?(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\((?:[^)(]+|(?3))*+\))}', $user_agent, $matches)`, o que diminui um elemento do array (o `(?:` faz o trecho dentro do parênteses não ser um grupo de captura e ele não é retornado no array). Mas a posição 0 do array não dá pra eliminar, pq ela **sempre** terá todo o trecho que foi capturado pela regex. O único jeito é tratar os dados do array manualmente, como eu fiz...

Comment: Entendi a situação, só adaptar a lógica e pronto, foi de grande ajuda @hkotsubo.