# Expressão Regular - Split desconsiderando o que estiver dentro de parênteses

Tags: java, regex

Alguém pode me ajudar com uma expressão regular em Java que separe o texto pelo `.` (ponto) desconsiderando o que estiver dentro dos parênteses.
Por exemplo:

```
abacaxi.laranja.(pera.banana)limao.mamao
```

Tem que gerar o resultado

```
abacaxi
laranja
(pera.banana)limao
mamao
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é detectar que o ponto está dentro de parênteses, pois a regex deve verificar se há a abertura e o fechamento correspondente, e se estão devidamente balanceados, etc (além do caso de ter parênteses dentro de outros). E para isso você precisaria usar [regex recursiva](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html), que o Java **não** suporta. E mesmo que suportasse, não é a forma mais simples de resolver esse problema (para ter uma ideia de como é uma regex recursiva, veja exemplos [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/354598/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/371443/112052)).

Acho que é mais simples percorrer a string e manter uma contagem dos parênteses, e ir guardando as posições dos pontos, ignorando os que estão dentro de parênteses.

Em seguida eu uso estas posições para obter trechos da string, usando o [método `substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-):

```
String s = "abacaxi.laranja.(pera.banana)limao.mamao";
int open = 0; // contagem de parênteses abertos
List<Integer> posicoes = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (c == '(') {
        open++;
    } else if (c == ')') {
        open--;
    } else if (c == '.' && open == 0) {
        // achei um ponto que não está dentro de parênteses
        posicoes.add(i);
    }
}

List<String> partes = new ArrayList<>();
int posInicial = 0;
for (int pos : posicoes) {
    // usar as posições em que estão os pontos para obter substrings
    partes.add(s.substring(posInicial, pos));
    posInicial = pos + 1;
}
// não esquecer de adicionar o último trecho (do último ponto até o final da string)
partes.add(s.substring(posInicial));
System.out.println(partes);
```

O resultado é uma lista com 4 elementos (ao imprimir o `List`, os elementos são mostrados assim, separados por vírgula):

> [abacaxi, laranja, (pera.banana)limao, mamao]

Este código funciona inclusive para parênteses dentro de outros (por exemplo, se a string for `abacaxi.laranja.(pera.banana(abc.def.ghi))limao.mamao`, todo o trecho `(pera.banana(abc.def.ghi))limao` é considerado uma coisa só).

---

*O código acima assume que os pares de parênteses estarão sempre certos (para cada `(` haverá o `)` correspondente). Como não está claro o que deve acontecer se tiver parênteses desbalanceados (com `(` ou `)` faltando ou sobrando), vou deixar assim por enquanto.*

---

#### Não dá mesmo para usar regex?

Apesar do Java não suportar regex recursiva, você pode fazer uma regex **limitada** para o seu caso específico (dentro de um par de parênteses **não** pode ter outro par de parênteses). Mas em vez de `split`, vou usar um [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) para buscar os trechos que eu quero (que dá no mesmo, afinal, `split` e `match` [são dois lados da mesma moeda](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#splitvsmatch) - o que muda é a lógica: no `split` eu digo o que **não** quero que esteja no resultado final, e no `match` eu digo o que quero):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?:\\([^()]+\\))?[^.()]+(?=\\.|$)").matcher(s);
partes = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    partes.add(matcher.group(0));
}
System.out.println(partes);
```

O resultado é o mesmo do código anterior. O trecho `(?:\\([^()]+\\))?` procura por parênteses `\\(` e `\\)` que tenham dentro deles quaisquer caracteres que **não** sejam parênteses (o trecho `[^()]+`), e o `?` no final torna todo este trecho opcional.

Em seguida temos `[^.()]+`, que é "um ou mais caracteres que não sejam parênteses nem ponto".

E depois temos o [*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (o trecho com `(?=`), e dentro dele temos `\\.|$` (um ponto ou o fim da string). O detalhe é que o *lookahead* só verifica o que tem na frente, mas ele não faz parte do *match*.

Em seguida eu verifico todos os *matches* e adiciono na lista. No final tenho a lista com as partes desejadas.

Lembrando que esta regex assume que não há parênteses dentro de outros, e que os pares sempre estão balanceados. Para strings com parênteses dentro de outros, é melhor usar o primeiro código que sugeri (mas ele também assume que os pares estão balanceados).

Outro detalhe é que ela só verifica parênteses que ocorrem logo depois do ponto. Se a string for `"abacaxi.laranja(pera.banana).mamao"`, você pode mudar para:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[^.()]*(?:\\([^()]+\\))?[^.()]*(?=\\.|$)").matcher(s);
partes = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    String parte = matcher.group(0);
    if (parte.length() > 0)
        partes.add(parte);
}
System.out.println(partes);
```

Agora eu uso `*` em vez de `+` (para pegar [zero ou mais ocorrências](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)). Por isso agora eu preciso testar se as partes têm tamanho zero, pois algumas strings vazias são capturadas por esta regex. Mas - novamente - esta regex não funciona para parênteses dentro de outros (para estes casos, prefira o primeiro código, sem regex).

Comment: Utilizei o Regex, e funcionou perfeitamente.
Muito obrigado pela ajuda.